# Javascript multiplication w/value stored in another cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, multiplication

---

Update: Final Fix:

```
        $('.gasamount').sum();
        var num = $(this).attr("id").replace(/[A-Za-z$,-]/g, "");
        $('#gasmoney'+num).val(<cfoutput>#mileage#</cfoutput> * $(this).val());
        $('.gasmoney').sum();
```

---

What I've been trying to accomplish:

- Create a set value for a row of cells.
- Multiply the user's value by a stored amount.
- Get that result and display the value in the cell directly below it in the next row.

I can't seem to get this to work. Every time I think I'm close I'm returning objects or an undefined value.

**Javascript**

---

```
    $('.calc').change(function(){
        var classArray = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');

        $.each(classArray, function(){

            var totalsum = $('.'+this).sum();
            $('.ttl'+this).val(Number(totalsum).toFixed(2));

            var gas = $('.gasamount4');
            var gasAmt = gas.val() * <cfoutput>#mileage#</cfoutput>;
            var gasTot = $('gasmoney4').val(gasAmt);
            gasTot;
            alert(gasTot);
        });

        //Finding the grandtotal
        var grandTotal = $('.row26').parent().children('td:last').children( 'input');
        var sum = $('.row25').parent().children('td').children('.calc').sum();
        grandTotal.val(Number(sum).toFixed(2));
    });
```

**ColdFusion / HTML**

---

```
        <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(labels)#" index="r">
        <tr>
            <td class="labels"><cfif ArrayIsDefined(labels,r) AND labels[r] NEQ "Open">#labels[r]#</cfif></td>
            <cfloop from="1" to="7" index="i">
            <td id="Day#i#" class="row#r# col#i#">
                <cfif r EQ 1>#Left(DayOfWeekAsString(i),3)#<cfelse><cfif r EQ 2><input type="text" class="date-mask" /><cfelse><input type="text" class="calc <cfif labels[r] EQ "Personal Car: Mileage ##">gasamount#i# </cfif> <cfif labels[r] EQ "Personal Car: Mileage $">gasmoney#i# </cfif><cfif labels[r] EQ "Daily Totals">ttlC#i#<cfelse>R#r# C#i#</cfif><cfif labels[r] EQ "Grand Total">gTtl#r#</cfif>" <cfif labels[r] EQ "Daily Totals" OR labels[r] EQ "Personal Car: Mileage $">readonly="readonly"</cfif> /></cfif></cfif></td>
            </cfloop>
            <td class="totals"><cfif r EQ 1>Total<cfelse><input type="text" class="ttlR#r#" readonly="readonly" /></cfif></td>
        </tr>
        </cfloop>
```

If something wasn't made clear, just ask and I'll do my best to provide any additional information. Thanks.

Comment: An actual *problem description* would be a good start. :) Having a goal is good, but deciphering somebody else's code with no idea what's wrong does not work so well, for me at least.

Comment: ... This is MY code..  if you're referring to "I'll do my best to provide any additional information.", it's in case someone isn't familiar with coldfusion and what not.. BTW. A problem is stated. "I've been trying",, in other words, I can't. Programmers typically have firebug, thus they should be able to see additional code for themselves. Thank you though..

Comment: It's always easier to look at the html output, not the server side stuff.  Have you used console.log(totalSum) and console.log(gasTot) and console.log(grandTotal) to see where the math breaks down?

Comment: Yes, but I get the same results. Objects and empty strings. Thank you though, not a lot of people use that valuable resource for debugging.

Comment: Honestly - becoming pissed with the people that can potentially help you is not it. Getting answers that begin with "From the code, I speculate ..." pretty much proves that the question is lacking some detail.

Comment: I was simply trying to reiterate while being a bit more assertive. Wanted to clear up your "assumption".

Answer (score 1):

From the code, I speculate that you want to take the number in each cell of the "Personal Car Mileage #" row, multiply it by the user's mileage rate, and put the result in the corresponding cell in the "Personal Car Mileage $" row.

Try this:

```
$('input.R4').change(function () {
    var val = this.value,
    cell = this.className.match(/C\d+/)[0];

    val = parseInt(val, 10);
    val *= <cfoutput>#mileage#</cfoutput>;
    $('td.row5 input.' + cell)[0].value = val.toFixed(2);
});
```

Edit:

$('input.R4') should be selecting every input element with a class of "R4", so this will be every input element on the "Personal Car Mileage #" row.

The "cell" variable (poorly named, in retrospect) captures the column of the cell that just changed.  So, if you change the first input box, this will be "C1".

Ergo, $('td.row5 input.C1') will then capture the input with class "C1" in the fifth row of the table (the "Personal Car Mileage $" row), and set its value to the computed amount.

So, it should already be working for each cell in the row.  This is possible because you've given your rows, cells, and input elements helpful class names--but take care, numeric values may be subject to change at some later date.  If somebody after you inserts a new row into the table, thus throwing off the numbers, this code is likely to break.

You're on the right track by adding "gasamountX" and "gasmoneyX" to these things, but I think you should take the numbers off them.  If you do, you can change the code to:

```
$('input.gasamount').change(function () {
    var val = this.value,
    column = this.className.match(/C\d+/)[0];

    val = parseInt(val, 10);
    val *= <cfoutput>#mileage#</cfoutput>;
    $('input.gasmoney.' + column)[0].value = val.toFixed(2);
});
```

Make sense?

Comment: Chris, thanks so much for your input! I added this and tested it. It seems to be working for that individual cell. I'm going to make some changes and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Chris, do you have an idea as to how it could work for each cell in that entire row. For example, instead of 'input.R4' I'd use '.gasamount'+this ?

Comment: Makes sense, but not it. Going to change my approach a bit. I'll post it when I make the changes.

Comment: I came up with a solution to that problem. I added two distinct ids and was able to manipulate that way. Check out the new code.